Definition of degree of a vector bundle?
Sorry if this question is extremely basic. I'm trying to understand the definition of degree of a vector bundle over a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$, using the additivity of degree on exact sequences. This is mentioned in page 2 of these lecture notes.
In most literature I can find, it seems to be the case where the degree of a vector bundle over a curve is defined as the degree of the determinant line bundle. However, I am interested in how a vector bundle fits inside an exact sequence involving line bundles, as suggested in this case.
What exactly is the exact sequence we have to consider in this situation?

Any vector bundle $E$ on a curve $C$ has a rational section, i.e., a section defined on the complement of a finite set of points. Such a section extends to a fiberwise embedding $L \to E$ from a line bundle $L$ over $C$, and thus gives an exact sequence
$$
0 \to L \to E \to E' \to 0,
$$
where $E'$ is a vector bundle of smaller rank.

The part obtaining $L$ from a rational section still feels a little obscure to me, but I think I've found material covering this. Thanks!
